# Lambda Sort on Long Types

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

I'm trying to run a sort as below but am running into an issue with the `Start` properties being of type Long in the Lambda expression. When they were of type int this was working correctly but I need this to work over larger values. I've tried casting the `a.Start - b.Start` to int but this seems to provide an incorrect sort result.

Is there a different method by which I should be sorting or should I change datatypes?

```
ranges.Sort((a, b) => a.Start - b.Start);
```

[image]

```
private readonly List<Range> ranges = new List<Range>();
public class Range
{
    public Range(long startEnd) : this(startEnd, startEnd)
    {
    }

    public Range(long start, long end)
    {
        if (end >= start)
        {
            Start = start;
            End = end;
        }
        else
        {
            Start = end;
            End = start;
        }
    }

    public long Start { get; private set; }
    public long End { get; private set; }

    public void Update(long newStart, long newEnd)
    {
        Start = newStart;
        End = newEnd;
    }

    public static implicit operator Range(long i)
    {
        return new Range(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function you pass to `Sort` should:

- return anything negative if a < b (can be always -1 for example)
- zero if a == b
- anything positive if a > b (can be always 1 for example)

Your current function satisfies this criteria (but not safe to use because of potential overflow), but returns `long`. There are many other functions that satisfy this criteria though. One is already existing comparer for longs:

```
ranges.Sort((a, b) => a.Start.CompareTo(b.Start));
```

You can do the same yourself if you'd like (though no reason to):

```
ranges.Sort((a, b) => a.Start > b.Start ? 1 : a.Start < b.Start ? -1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

The delegate you pass to the `Sort` method is a [`Comparison<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) which must *always return an `int`*, whatever the type `T` it is comparing.

The `int` returned from this delegate should be:

> A signed integer that indicates the relative values of x and y, as
>   shown in the following table.
>
> ```
> Value             Meaning
>
> Less than 0       x is less than y.
>
> 0                x equals y.
>
> Greater than 0   x is greater than y.
> ```

Therefore the fact that it worked when your `Start` was an `int` is actually purely coincidental.

You can fix your case by having your delegate return

```
a.Start.CompareTo(b.Start)
```

Answer (score 1):

A comparison is supposed to return an `int` so you need to convert your `long` to an `int` somehow.  You can either `Convert.ToInt32` or, if that might be out of range, simply return `-1` for any negative value and `1` for any positive value.

Another, probably better alternative, would be to use the `CompareTo` method of one of the values for both `int` and `long`, which would be functionally equivalent to the second option.

Answer (score 1):

Casting `a.Start - b.Start` to int seems to work here, however by doing that you expose yourself to overflow errors (what if `a.Start` is 0 and `b.Start` is `long.MaxValue`, for example?). Since `Sort` only checks if your lambda is returning a positive value, a negative value or zero, you can do just this:

```
ranges.Sort((a, b) => a.Start > b.Start ? 1 : a.Start < b.Start ? -1 : 0);
```

Alternatively, LINQ's `OrderBy` works just fine (and is not limited to `List`s), but be aware that it returns a new object rather than modifying the original one, which may or may not be ok for you:

```
ranges = ranges.OrderBy(r => r.Start).ToList()
```